# How to force browser to wait until php server sends a response?

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I have the following setup:

- Client: The browser
- Server A: The server that hosts my PHP application
- Server B: Storage server

So, server B has a lot of data that users download when they need. The client sends a request to server A asking for that file, server A connects to Server B through SSH and performs multiple tasks (including decryption and compression), after these tasks are completed a zip file is generated on server B, then server A redirects the request made using `header("Location: https://serverb.com/index.php?file=thefileiwant.zip")`.

The problem is that if there are a lot of files (I am testing with 50), the zip file is downloaded with 0 bytes. For a small amount of files  everything works fine so I think the problem is that decryption and compression is taking too long and the server just sends and empty file because the request times out...

How can I solve this?

Edit to add more info:

- The resulting file would be just 4mb so I don't think this is the problem.
- Already increased the max_execution_time on php_ini (although it doesn't seem to have worked, since I get the 0 bytes zip before the 2 minutes..
- Already added these to the file

  ob_implicit_flush();

  ini_set('max_execution_time','120');

  header('Expires: 0');

  set_time_limit(0);

Comment: a browser will always wait for php, as php is server-side and it finishes before talking to the browser, think we need see some actual code here

Comment: you are right @IdontDownVote the problem wasn't a timeout, thanks to you I figured it out (I posted an anser below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @IdontDownVote, the problem is not that the browser wasn't waiting, the problem was with the ssh connection:

Here is how I was zipping the files:

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'zip -j '.$path.$zipname.'.zip '.$path.'*.txt '.$path.'*.3gp');
```

The problem is that this just sends the command to Server B and jumps to the next line, so the zip file was never finished. I realized that when I saw several files with a name pattern like `zid5Jhn` instead of the actual zip file (this along with @IdontDownVote comment)

I solved this using the function I was using to get the command output:

```
function get_command_return($connection, $command){
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    return stream_get_contents($stream_out);
}
```

So I solved it by changing `ssh2_exec(...) to get_command_return(...)` although I think only the line `stream_set_blocking($stream, true);` was necessary

Thank you